# Passing variable from Authenticator to endpoint JAX-RS and RESTlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, jax-rs, restlet

I have a custom authenticator (ie. a class that extends Authenticator and does some custom authentication in authenticate(Response res, Request req)) that I then want to pass a value to the function that handles the actual API call. I thought adding an argument like `@Context Request request` could work but I don't think so.

Anyone know how I can pass an object from Authenticator to resource?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

jax-rs has a mechanism for that. You can create a custom context that implements SecurityContext. This security context returns your your user object as Principal.
Your authenticator which probably works as a filter can then set the security context of your request. From there on you can access your User object via the SecurityContext.

While not perfect, I have a [working piece of code on github](https://github.com/konqi/fit-precinct/blob/master/src/main/java/de/konqi/fitapi/rest/webapi/filter/OAuthRequestFilter.java) that can get you started.

Comment: Could you by chance expand it with the router and endpoint to see how it all comes together?

Comment: Just browse through the source, you should find what you're looking for.